# How do I get that ability to dash through long areas of spikes?

Tags: hollow-knight

In Hollow Knight there are places where there are spikes on the floor and ceiling, for example right next to the bench in the ancient basin or a small area after the false knight fight. I know I need some sort of long dash to get across.
Is there a boss I need to defeat in order to gain that ability?

I can handle spoilers of what I need to do, just please don't spoil the lore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ability found in the Crystal Peak area of the game, to the upper right of the map. The arrows in the below screenshot show the point of entry from the forgotten crossroad -- you will need the Desolate Dive magic ability to access the area via the upper path depicted in the image below.
Otherwise you can get there through the lower path in the image with the lantern from the shop in Dirtmouth.

[image]

Comment: You can also bounce on some spikes with the air down attack. It will bump you up a bit in the air and you can go left or right but you must have a good timing to master it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Only problem is i hate the crystal peaks with a burning passion :)

Comment: @Chocobouc I tried that in the ancient basin, and while you can bounce on the spikes there, you can't make the final jump to get up there without the double jump :-(

Comment: There is an alternate entrance to the Crystal Peak that requires the lantern and some geo instead of the Desolate Dive (right below the arrow on the map).

Comment: There should be two arrows, but the part with the lanterns is usefull to add, thanks @murgatroid99